# Manipulate CSV file using groovy and java

Tags: java, csv, groovy

Newbie here with a question. I have the following .csv file as an example:

```
10;06.07.2022;This is test;

08;01.07.2020;This is test;

15;06.07.2021;This is test;

09;06.07.2021;This is test;
```

So its multiple rows with the same setup. I want to delete each row which have a date earlier then 06.07.2022. So in theory only the first row should still be in the .csv file and the other ones should get deleted.

I want to be able to declare the date as a variable.
I already did the following to try to understand:

```
     private String dateii      = 'test.csv';                               // Filename Input
     private String dateio      = '';                                           // Filename Output


void openInputfile() {
        File outputfile = new File(dateio);
        outputfile.write('');
        
        File inputfile = new File(dateii);
        if (!inputfile.exists()) {
             println("No File")

        }
            
        List data = inputfile.readLines();
        for (String zeile in data) {
            
            
            if (zeile.startsWith('BEREICH')) {
                Header = zeile;
            } else {
                List buffer = zeile.split(";");
                if (zeile.size() > 0) {                                     // Remove Empty rows
                    
                    
                }
            } 
        }
```

EDIT:

So my questions are the following:

1. How can I delete a complete row?
2. How can I specify which rows to delete using the date?

Thank you!

Comment: why there are 2 languages in tags - java & groovy ? which one will be accepted as response?

Comment: @daggett Hello! Both are accepted. I can use both but don't know which one is better. I'm trying to use more groovy then Java

Comment: @Eritrean Hello thanks for your help! I edited the question to be more precise. I hope this clears it up a bit. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the input file `projects/test.csv` containing these lines:

```
10;06.07.2022;This is test;
08;01.07.2020;This is test;
15;06.07.2021;This is test;
09;06.07.2021;This is test;
```

The following Groovy script:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.LocalDate

final FMT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('dd.MM.yyyy')

def targetDate = LocalDate.parse('06.07.2022', FMT)

def test = new File('projects/test.csv')
def filtered = new File('projects/filtered.csv')
def filteredOutput = filtered.newPrintWriter()

test.filterLine(filteredOutput) { line ->
   def parts = line.split(';')
   def lineDate = LocalDate.parse(parts[1], FMT)
   lineDate >= targetDate
}
```

Produces the following output in file `projects/filtered.csv`:

```
10;06.07.2022;This is test;
```

Is this what you were looking for?

It takes advantage of idiomatic Groovy code shortcuts and modern `java.time` date manipulation classes.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you very much :)
I polished it a bit and played with arguments so whenever I call the program I can say in which column the date is stored and also the targetDate is a argument now. Thanks Thanks Thanks!

Comment: I'm currently finishing my program. Is there a possibility to say at which line it should start? So for example I want to skip the first 3 lines and then start the filtering. Thank you!

Comment: RE start line: 1) Define an integer variable initialized to zero (0) above the `filterLine` call. 2) Increment the variable on the first line INSIDE the closure in the `filterLine` call. 3) Modify the the boolean expression on the LAST line inside that closure to first check that the integer variable is greater than the skip count (something like this: `i <= skipLines || lineDate >= targetDate`).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a schoolwork assignment, so I’ll be brief and omit code.

First, define your target date as a `LocalDate` object.

```
LocalDate target = LocalDate.of( 2021 , 6 , 7 ) ;
```

Your existing code has a list of fields for each row. Your goal is to filter by comparing the second field, the date.

1. Extract the second field, the date input.
2. Parse that date input as a `LocalDate`. Use a `DateTimeFormatter` object for parsing, with a formatting pattern you define.
3. Compare dates using `LocalDate#isBefore`.
4. If your criterion is met, write that line to the output file. If not met, move on to the next line, omitting this current line from your output file.

All aspects of this have been covered many many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Tip: [Java NIO.2](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java+nio.2). Java has old ways of handling files, and new ways. Use the new ways.

You asked:

> How can I delete a complete row?

Skip it. Don’t write that line to the output file.

You asked:

> How can I specify which rows to delete using the date?

Parse the text of the date field as a `LocalDate`. Compare to your target date using a `LocalDate` method such as `isAfter` or `isBefore`.

---

By the way, better naming will make your code easier to read and debug. `data` is vague. `buffer` is [inaccurate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer). `Header` should start with a lowercase letter, `header`.

---

In real work we would not parse the CSV file directly. We would use any of the several good CSV parsing libraries available in the Java ecosystem. Example: [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

Answer (score 1):

in groovy code could look like this if input file this simple - otherwise better to use csv library

```
import java.time.LocalDate

//could be replaced with src = new File(source_file_name)
def src = '''
10;30.07.2022;This is test;
08;01.07.2020;This is test;
15;06.07.2021;This is test;
09;06.07.2021;This is test;
'''

//could be replaced with dst = new File(target_file_name)
def dst = System.out
def now = LocalDate.now()

dst.withWriter{writer->
    src.eachLine{line->
        def row = line.split(/;/)
        if( row.size()==3 ){
            if( LocalDate.parse(row[1], 'dd.MM.yyyy').toEpochDay() > now.toEpochDay() ) {
                writer << line << '\n'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both of the terribly flawed `Date` classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: it's not yet deprecated - right? however Date easily could be replaced with LocalTime if there is a need.

Comment: @daggett Considering the use case `Date` could probably only be *easily* replaced with `LocalDate`, since `LocalTime` does not have a calendar date component.